# how to filter option from select reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to filter or not show the option in the select if a specific value is selected.

[image]

Select Component (antd select) above has 4 options, if case the user selected "ALL" select box should only show ALL. (i.e) If "RED" and "BLUE" is already selected, and the user selects "ALL" next, the select box should only should "ALL".

User can select multiple option but if "ALL" selected the field should show only "ALL".

**Code:**

```
const optionValues = ["ALL", "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN"];

const { Option } = Select;
const children = [];

optionValues.forEach((op, index) => {
  children.push(
    <Option key={index} value={op}>
      {op}
    </Option>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setCategory(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(category);
  }, [category]);

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        mode="tags"
        placeholder="Please select"
        onChange={handleChange}
        style={{
          width: "100%"
        }}
      >
        {category.includes("ALL") ? "ALL" : children}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};
```

In the above code, the select is still shows other categories, even if "ALL" is selected.

**Step to reproduce:**

1. Select "RED" or "BLUE" or "GREEN" or Multiple
2. Select "ALL"

**Codesandbox link:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd-4-21-7-forked-jqnkbv?file=/demo.js

Comment: I think you need to pass value prop in select component. Try to add in select and see if it works for you `value={category.includes("ALL") ? ["ALL"] : category}`

Answer (score 0):

In the `onChange` function you need to check if the `value` `includes` `ALL`, if yes, you need to reset the `category` state to contains only `ALL`, and you should provide a `value` for the `Select`

Please check

https://codesandbox.io/s/sizes-antd-4-21-7-forked-ttqpkf